# Create Spreadsheet in .NET Compact Framework 3.5

Tags: compact-framework, spreadsheet

I hope this is not a repetitive question; I've searched on the site but I was not able to find anything.
As the title say I would like to create/edit spreadsheet on a .NET Compact Framework project.
On desktop project with the full size framework I use, with pleasure, ClosedXML but if I try to use this I get multiple errors so I'm searching for an alternative.

I have found a commercial option (TMS Flexcel Studio for .NET) but I was wondering if there is something free to use.

I know that I could simply create a csv but I want to do something a bit more modern.

Thanks in advance to everyone who will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after trying a lot of free librery i found a solution.

Excellibrary works! [link to google code](https://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/)

I have tried it with Visual Studio 2008 in combination with a Windows CE 5 device and it created an xls file easily.
I must test it to check the performance but at least it works and it's free.
Also the sintax is very simple

```
Dim file As String = "\HardDisk\newdoc.xls"
Dim workbook As New Workbook()
Dim worksheet As New SpreadSheet.Worksheet("First Sheet")
worksheet.Cells(3, 3) = New Cell(3.45)
workbook.Worksheets.Add(worksheet)
workbook.Save(file)
```