# Creating excel in windows mobile 5.5devices using vb.net

Tags: windows, excel, visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile

Currently I am working in windows mobile 5.5 devices. I want to create and write excel files. I tried in web they told to add some dll(object library). But no luck. I can't get in vs2008. If any one know how to create excel in windows mobile 5.5 devices using vb.net. Please give any references.

Comment: AFAIR you need the Windows Mobile 6.5 SDK/DTK and then add a reference to the Windows.WindowsMobile.Office (from my brain) COM library.

Answer (score 0):

See [Create Spreadsheet in .NET Compact Framework 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23562787/create-spreadsheet-in-net-compact-framework-3-5)

> "Ok, after trying a lot of free librery i found a solution.
>
> Excellibrary works! link to google code
>
> I have tried it with Visual Studio 2008 in combination with a Windows
>   CE 5 device and it created an xls file easily. I must test it to check
>   the performance but at least it works and it's free. Also the sintax
>   is very simple
>
> Dim file As String = "\HardDisk\newdoc.xls" Dim workbook As New
>   Workbook() Dim worksheet As New SpreadSheet.Worksheet("First Sheet")
>   worksheet.Cells(3, 3) = New Cell(3.45)
>   workbook.Worksheets.Add(worksheet) workbook.Save(file)"